# My footer doesn't show all the content when the screen size gets shorter

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer, react-bootstrap

My footer's last part(the "address" part disappear when the screen's height is shorter than some certain points, around 938), I wonder why?

The HTML looks like this:

```
      <div className="container-fluid footer">
          <div className="container contact-block">
             <h3> Contact </h3>
             <p>Telephone:  </p>
             <p>Address:  </p>         
          </div>            
      </div>
```

So my footer's CSS looks like this:

```
.footer{
  height: 12%;
  background-color: rgb(54, 58, 57);
  margin-top: 2%;
  color: antiquewhite;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
}
...
.contact-block{
  padding: 1%;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
```

BTW, I use react-bootstrap for styling too

Comment: Probably because you have a `height: 12%;`, does it work when that is removed?

Comment: @Dejan.S Thank you! It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the `height: 12%;` after a certain limit the height becomes too small and cannot contain the elements.

I would reconsider using a percentage as the height but if you really want to, then I would at least put something like `min-height: 100px;` (or whatever min-height works based on your styles), I believe that should solve the issue :)